# Correct Apache Configuration And Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I've just reset my Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP server hosted with digital ocean. Could someone tell me the 'proper' way to do server configuration. My goal is to do everything as clean as possible (and hopefully well structured).

I intend on using the server mainly for programming and data analytics, however I do plan on hosting my website in /var/www/html. I also plan on using letsencrypt/certbot to get an easy SSL. With this in mind, these are the main goals I would like to accomplish:

1) Redirect the website to ALWAYS be served through https AND www. 
2) Enable HSTS for the entire website. 
3) Enable clean url's (remove .php extensions and what not).

Since I would like all of these properties to be used across the entire website, should the configuration be done inside of the /etc/apache2/ folder? Or should it be done inside of .htaccess?

And if it should be done inside of apache2 configuration, which file should I add it to? And finally, how exactly should it be added? (for example vhost 80/443, inside of a mod_something section, etc).

Thank you in advance, I would appreciate and consider any advice about Apache and htaccess!

Comment: Never use `.htaccess` style dynamic configuration files wherever you can get around it. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server process, often for nothing.

Comment: Your question reads as if you have not really tried to understand the logic behind the setup as offered by the standard packages you installed. Instead of asking here you should five into the configuration files, read the comments in there and get a feeling for the setup. It is impossible for us to tell you exactly where to put what. You need to _understand_ what you are doing, you should not blindly follow some advice you get from some site in the web.

Comment: @arkascha thank you for your assistance :)